# SignalR save groups to database

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, database, signalr, signalr-backplane

I have problems with SignalR under redundancy servers. I'm reading the last days on internet every tutorial/document, but my Signal R Server application(ASP.NET MVC 5) don't work under redundancy servers.

What I've done so far:

- Implemented Scaleout With SQL Server (link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/performance/scaleout-with-sql-server)
- Saved custom HubClients to database en getting from there (and filled the HubGroups with Groups.add() method)

But none of this solution works well. What I will know is how to save the Hub.Groups (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.aspnet.signalr.hub.groups(v=vs.118).aspx) object of Signal R in the database and get it from there.

I'm also wondering how the method Groups.Add/Remove() works internally. If the HubClients exists in the group, then he updates it or add the HubClient again to the group? All this information must be on MSDN, but there is nothing!!

Can someone give me a simple example of a SignalR server Web Application (MVC 5) with Scaleout functionality to save/get the Groups in/from the database?

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean by "Redundancy Servers"? Are redundancy servers additional web front ends that you've added to scale out your application, or are these some kind of hot standby servers that will only receive traffic in the event of failure?

Comment: Also, note that the complete SignalR source code is on GitHub. You can always pull it and look through if you have a question on how something is implemented.